# FFMPEG How to make a video with image concat demuxer, transition effects

Tags: image, image-processing, ffmpeg

I made a video with images concat demuxer txt file.
But I want to put some fade in/out transition on my video.
All other samples are use `-loop` option for set images.
How can I make images concat demuxer with transition effects to a video?

here's my args

> "ffmpeg", "-f", "concat", "-safe", "0", "-i", "images/input.txt",
>   "-i",
>           "input.mp3", "OUTPUT.mp4"

i'm working on java by the way

Comment: If you **need** to use the concat demuxer then make lossless temporary intermediate videos that have fades applied using the fade filter, or a better method is to use the concat filter. See [Create video with 5 images with fadeIn/out effect in ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/a/834035/110524).

Comment: @BOORO did you find any solution?